# Add multiple items to List in a MVC post view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model

My main point is to add multiple item rows at the same time in a View.
I have tried alot of different ways and I would like some help.

I appreciate suggestions on how to fix this issue. I am grateful for everything. Code-reviews, feedback, links, guides, information, help, messages. Anything related to this issue.

[The Models](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRIVc.png)

Here is my final code.

```
public class Order
{
    public int OrderID { get; set; }

    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<OrderRowDetails> OrderRowDetails { get; set; }
}
```

Employee Model:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
}
```

OrderRowDetails:

```
public class OrderRowDetails
{
    public int OrderRowDetailsID { get; set; }
    public int OrderID { get; set; }
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public int ProductTypeID { get; set; }
    public virtual ProductType ProductType { get; set; }
}

public class ProductType
{
    public int ProductTypeID { get; set; }
    public string ProductTypeName { get; set; }
}
```

Now I use a View Model:

```
public class OrderViewModel
{
    public int OrderID { get; set; }

    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<OrderRowDetails> OrderRowDetails { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Employee> Employees { get; set; }

    public int OrderRowDetailsID { get; set; }
    public int ProductID1 { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public int Quantity1 { get; set; }

    public int ProductID2 { get; set; }
    public int Quantity2 { get; set; }
    public int ProductID3 { get; set; }
    public int Quantity3 { get; set; }

    public OrderViewModel()
    {
       OrderRowDetails = new List<OrderRowDetails>();

    }
```

This is my Create View:

```
 @model TheProject1.ViewModel.OrderViewModel  
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Employee ID: (1)</th>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EmployeeID)</td>
    </tr>      
<tr>
<th>Product ID: (1-2)</th>
<td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.ProductID1)</td>
</tr>


    <tr>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Quantity1)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Product ID: (1-2)</th>
        <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.ProductID2)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Quantity2)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Product ID: (1-2)</th>
        <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.ProductID3)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Quantity3)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="submit"  value="Save" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>


    Controller:
    public ActionResult Create()
    {           
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Create(OrderViewModel orderView, Order order,               OrderRowDetails orderRowDetails)
    {

        var theorder = new Order()
        {
            EmployeeID = orderView.EmployeeID,
            OrderID = orderView.OrderID,
            OrderRowDetails = new List<OrderRowDetails>()
            {

                new OrderRowDetails()
                {
                    OrderID = orderView.OrderID,
                    ProductID = orderView.ProductID1,
                    Quantity = orderView.Quantity1
                },
                                    new OrderRowDetails()
                {
                    OrderID = orderView.OrderID,
                    ProductID = orderView.ProductID2,
                    Quantity = orderView.Quantity2
                },
                                                        new OrderRowDetails()
                {
                    OrderID = orderView.OrderID,
                    ProductID = orderView.ProductID3,
                    Quantity = orderView.Quantity3
                },
            }
        };


        db.Orders.Add(theorder);
        db.SaveChanges();

        // OrderID == OrderID
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Order");
```

I have lost is o much so my idea was to create 5 rows and hence I cant have nulls. My idea was to create an alternative that product ID = 1 is "No Value"
And before Adding to Database I would delete row where ProductID 1 from OrderRowDetails table.

```
    <tr>
        <th>Product ID: (1-2)</th>
        <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.ProductID)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Quantity)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Product ID: (1-2)</th>
        <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.ProductID)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Quantity)</td>
    </tr>
```

If I do this I get the values from the first OrderRow, 2 times.

My goal is to add multiple items in the list(OrderRowDetails) with the relationshop to Order (with OrderID).

I would really love if somebody could give me any information or teach me how to solve this.

Comment: Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019793/submit-same-partial-view-called-multiple-times-data-to-controller/28081308#28081308) for some options

Comment: Thank you so much, Stephen :)